# Using a UIPickerview

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2, uipickerview, nsmenu

I have this code that i did on Xcode 4.2 in a tabbed application and it works perfectly but what i would like it to be is a drop down menu in to a picker view but I'm not to sure what code i will need to add can you guys help heres my code

```
.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    NSMutableArray *list;
    IBOutlet UILabel *picklabel;
}

@end


.m

#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerview:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}



-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [list count];
}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component { return [list objectAtIndex:row];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"you selected: %@" , [list objectAtIndex:row]];
    picklabel.text = string;

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [list addObject:@"Giraffe"];
    [list addObject:@"Water Bottle"];
    [list addObject:@"spinning Fan"];
    [list addObject:@"Hariy Monkey"];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details to understand your requirements.

Comment: hi i would basically like a page that has about 3 drop down menus and when i select something from the lists in the drop down menu i would like it to go to a table view if that is possible ?

Comment: some thing like these images       http://imgur.com/pugk8&yxdB1   http://imgur.com/pugk8&yxdB1#1

Comment: i really am very grateful of your help

Comment: can anyone else help me with the coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps:

- On selection of each pickerview, add that data to one mutable array
- Each time reload your table view with that data (mutable array)
- Selected data will get added to your tabular list.

Enjoy Coding :)

Comment: i hi thanks for that is there any chance you can code that i a beginner lol :)